# Object as a key value in HashMap and using in jsp

Tags: java, list, jsp, arraylist, hashmap

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "lectureHall_details")
public class LectureHall {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY  )
private int id;
private String Name;
private String code;
private String description;
private int capacity;
.......
}
```

This is how my LectureHall class look like.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "timeTable_details")
public class TimeTable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY  )
private int id;
@ManyToOne
private LectureHall lectureHall;
@ManyToOne
private Department department;
.....
}
```

This is how my TimeTable class look like.I want to make the key value of the Map as the LectureHall class attribute Name.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"view/{day}/lecturehalls"})
public ModelAndView viewLectureHalls(@PathVariable("day") String day) {

    List<TimeTable> lectureHalls = timeTableDao.getLectureHallsList(day);
    Map<LectureHall, List<TimeTable>> byHall = lectureHalls.stream()
                                                           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TimeTable::getLectureHall));

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("page");
    mv.addObject("title","TimeTable");
    mv.addObject("mondayTime",byHall);
    mv.addObject("userclickviewlecturehallarrangements",true);
    return mv;
}
```

what I can do for that?

Answer (score 0):

If I interpreted your question right, you want to know how to create a HashMap from LectureHalls to Strings. This will allow you to store a hall's Name as the value in the map entry. Here is how you would declare and instantiate this map:

```
Map<LectureHall, String> nameMap = new HashMap();
```

Did that answer your question?

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, please consider accepting it so that others will be able to find the information more easily. If not, let us know and someone can try to answer it better. Thanks!